# In TCL code - how to read a Windows text file?

Tags: powershell, tcl, newline

How to read a text file (Windows) in TCL?
I've written some PowerShell code which generates a text file with multiple values. The generated values serve as input data for further processing.

I need the required logic to read the content using TCL.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and provide a [mcve].

Comment: What does your Powershell code look like so far? And what is your input data?

Comment: There is quite a good tutorial on how to use tcl on the tutorialspoint website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a file holding text, assuming you know the file is called `INPUT_DATA.TXT` in the current directory:

```
set f [open "INPUT_DATA.TXT"];   # Or [open "INPUT_DATA.TXT" "r"]
set lineList [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f
```

This puts a *list* of *lines* of text in the variable `lineList`. To do this it `open`s the filename, which returns a “file handle” that I store in the variable `f`. Then (reading the next line of code from the innermost part outwards) I `read` the whole contents of the file from the file handle and `split` that big string by `\n` (newline) to get a list of all all the contents of the lines in the file. Finally, I `close` that file handle; they're not usually a good idea to keep open when you don't need them as the OS has a finite number available (though that finite number is pretty large).

Next, you'll need to do further work to get the code to *understand* the contents of the file. Alas, that's more data-format-dependent so there's not really a general rule.

---

If you were working with a *binary* file instead, you might instead do:

```
set f [open "INPUT_DATA.BIN" "rb"]
set data [read $f]
close $f
```

but binary data formats are *far more varied* than text data formats, so “what next?” is even more difficult to generalise for. Fortunately, binary data in Tcl isn't too hard; apart from that extra `b` in the `open`, binary data is just yet another string to Tcl, and Tcl's *good* at strings!

Comment: Also, on Windows if you have a full filename like `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\DATA.TXT`, either change the backslashes to `/` in Tcl code ___or___ put the filename in `{…}` instead of `"…"`. Without that, you'll get the filename corrupted.